# How to install Eureka version 3

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, eureka-forms

How to install version 3, it is not in cocoapods.
My pod file

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
target 'Project' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Eureka', '~> 3.0'
end
```

The result of the command pod install

> Analyzing dependencies
>   [!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
>
> - `Eureka (~> 3.0)` required by `Podfile`
>
> None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Eureka (~> 3.0)`.
>
> You have either:
>   * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update`.
>   * mistyped the name or version.
>   * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
>
> Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default.

I understand that the repository is not updated in cocoa pods?
What to do?

Comment: `pod 'Eureka', :podspec =>https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/blob/master/Eureka.podspec`? Or you can specify the git too.

Comment: Thank you! You helped me a lot. I used `pod 'Eureka', :tag => 'master', :git => 'https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka.git'`